# macOS booting into Windows Recovery mode after deleting Bootcamp Windows partition

Tags: macos, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition, startup

My Mac still boots into Windows recovery mode, automatically. I can still boot into macOS and everything works, however I want to remove this partition. When I first start my Mac it also shows up with a loading gear icon in the middle of my screen.

Running "`diskutil list`" gave me this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0

   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1

   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         250.8 GB   disk0s2


/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Kkr dikke schijf - G...⁩ 97.1 GB    disk1s1

   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 441.2 MB   disk1s2

   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s3

   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk1s4

   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Kkr dikke schijf⁩        15.2 GB    disk1s5

   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.2 GB    disk1s5s1
```

Which partition do I need to remove?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows partition has been removed. However, there will still be Windows boot files stored in the hidden EFI partition (`disk0s1`). These files can be removed by entering the commands given below.

> Note: If you have a legacy BIOS booting Windows, then these Windows boot files would normally not exist. In this case, the `rm` commands would produce an error message.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
cd /Volumes/EFI/EFI
rm -r Boot
rm -r Microsoft
cd ~
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```